# integration, laurent series, residue therorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

> Evaluate the integral $\int_\gamma f(z)dz,$ where $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$, and $0\leqslant t\leqslant2\pi$. For $f(z)$ equal to: $$\dfrac{e^z}{z^3},\quad\dfrac1{z^2\sin z},\quad\tanh z,\quad\dfrac1{\cos(2z)}.$$

I think I need to find the points where the functions are undefined??
So for the first one $z=0$, however, not too sure where to go from there?

I have solved;
i) The Laurent series is; $1/z^3 + 1/z^2 + \dots$
hence residue $= z(1/z^3 +1/z^2+ 1/z + \dots) $ at $z=0$ , so residue$=1/2$

therefore $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\pi i$

Comment: What does the Residue theorem tell you?

Comment: that I can use the Laurent series, given my function is differentiable and centered at $z_0$?

Comment: [Residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) tells you when you can write $$\oint f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum\text{Res}$$ so if $f$ is on a simply connected domain with a finite number of poles and $f$ is holomorphic in the domain except at the poles you can use theorem to find integral. So by finding the poles, of those functions you can exploit this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, I get 
$$
\frac{e^z}{z^3} = \frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{2z} + \cdots
$$
So I don't follow your expansion were you go from $\frac{1}{z^3}$ to $\frac{1}{6z}$. However, the residue is $1/2$ so 
$$
\oint f(z) dz = \pi i
$$
For the second problem, we have 
$$
\frac{1}{z^2\sin(z)} = \frac{1}{z^3(1 - z^2/(3!) + \cdots)}
$$
so we have a pole at $z = 0$ of order three. For three, we can write $\tanh(z)$ as 
$$
\tanh(z) = \frac{\sinh(z)}{\cosh(z)}\text{ or as } \frac{e^{z} - e^{-z}}{e^{z} + e^{-z}}
$$
If we use the second identity for $\tanh(z)$, we have a pole when $e^z+e^{-z} = 0\Rightarrow e^{2z} = -1 = e^{i\pi(1 + 2k)}$. We have poles when $2z = i\pi(1 + 2k)\Rightarrow z = \frac{i\pi}{2}(1+2k)$. Then
$$
2\pi i\lim_{z\to\pi i/2}(z-\pi i/2)\tanh(z) = 2\pi i
$$
For the final one, I would write $\cos(2z) = \frac{e^{2iz} + e^{-2iz}}{2}$. Then let $w = e^{iz}$ so $dw = ie^{iz}dz = iwdz$.
$$
\int_C\frac{dz}{\cos(2z)} = \int_C\frac{2dw}{iw(w^2 + w^{-2})} = \int_C\frac{2dw}{i(w^3 + w^{-1})} = \int_C\frac{2wdw}{i(w^4 + 1)}
$$ 
Let $w = re^{i\theta}$. Then 
\begin{align}
r^4e^{4i\theta} &= -1\\
&= e^{\pi i(1 + 2k)}
\end{align}
so $r =1$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}(1+2k)$ where are where the poles occur for $k = 0,1,2,3$.

Comment: a quick question for part 3. am i allowed to use the singularity even though it lies outside the unit circle?

Comment: any insight to the last comment would be extremely helpful